# How to get text inside html element using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As the title said, how do I get the text inside a div using angularjs ? IE:

```
<div class='container' ng-app=''>
    <input type='text' ng-model='qty'>
    <div class='price'></div>
    <div class='total'>{{qty * price}}</div>
</div>
```

The input is **editable** and can be filled with any numbers, while the price is **fixed**, not editable but it is different for every items, now how do I get the content of the price using AngularJS and multiply it with the qty inputted and show the total in the total div?

Comment: Provide the data (JSON?) you want to show please.

Comment: So basically, this should include looping right? Do you have `ng-repeat` implemented here?

Comment: Why do you want to get the value from DOM? The value is coming from angular model. right? To do binding you can use ng-bind, but the as value is already present in scope then why take from DOM.  Well there is no better way or angular way.

Comment: @amarmishra actually I use normal jquery to change the value of the price after the user selected the item, but since I just found out about angular I thought it could be useful rather than writing another script for this.

Comment: @Mistalis I am using jquery ajax to manipulate the price after a user selected a certain item.

Comment: @Charas ok man whatever gets us going. Cheers !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `initialize` values in controller.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.price= $('.price').text();
   $scope.qty=0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model='qty'>
    <div class="price">3.4</div>
    <div class='total'>Total: {{ qty * price }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the price is not going to be static as the example you gave, the price is going to keep changing using jquery ajax depending on the item selected by the user.

Comment: Please have a look now.